# Why the Reducer prev state is same as next state in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, redux

In my `staffReducer`, I tried to sign the staff was working.
I had a case as following:

```
const staffReducer = (state=[], action)=>{
 switch(action.type){
  case "SET_WORKING":
   let staff = state.find(x=> x.id == action.id);
   if (!staff.working) {
    staff.working = true;
   }else{
    staff.working = false;
   }
  break;
 }
 return state;
}
```

This code was working fined but I observed the `logger`,`prev state` and `next state` in the logger, I found two state is same, but in correct way, the `working` variable in `prev state` should be `false` and `next state` should be `true`.

Now two the working variable in two state are both `true`.

Is the code I way to wrong?

**UPDATE**

the Component code as following:

```
class ClockInContainer extends React.Component{
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state={
   staff: "",
  }
 }
 handleSelectValueChange = (key) => (event, index, value) =>{
    this.setState({[key]: value});
 }
 handleCreate(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  const {staff} = this.state;
  this.props.dispatch({type:"SET_WORKING", id:staff});
 }

 render(){
  return(
  <form onSubmit={this.handleCreate}>
    <input type="text" value={this.state.staff} onChange={this.handleSelectValueChange("staff")}/>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
 )
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducer is a pure function that in combination with action returns a new version of state or the same state in default case.

In the code you are making an implicit change to the object in array thus affecting every reference it is linked to in app immediately.

So to fix it:

```js
const staffReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_WORKING":
      return state.map((staff) => {
        if (action.id === staff.id) {
          return {
            ...staff,
            working: !staff.working
          }
        }
        return staff;
      })
    default:
      return state;
  }
}


// TO TEST the above
const initialState = [{
  id: 0,
  working: false
}, {
  id: 1,
  working: false
}, {
  id: 2,
  working: false
}]

console.log(initialState); // UNCHANGED

console.log(staffReducer(initialState, {
  type: "SET_WORKING",
  id: 2
})); // MODIFIED as expected
```

Explanation:

By `state.map` we return a new array copy, so the identity of array instance is different, which already breaks the reference to the previous version in the app.

But on its own it's not enough, since your change is on one level deeper, on the array item level in an object, so we have to also make sure that the identity of the object in the array is also different to tear the connection to it from old references, by using [object rest spread syntax](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) like this 

`return {
    ...staff,
    working: !staff.working
};`

Hope it helps.